# I get an error when I use LinkedIn share API

Tags: node.js, request, linkedin-api

I want share something on **LinkedIn** with API from `request` **NodeJS** package:

## My code:

```
Request({
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares',
    'headers': {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'x-li-format': 'json',
        'authorization': 'Bearer' + this.accessToken
    },
    'qs': {
        'format': 'json',
        'content': {
            'title': 'My title',
            'description': 'One description',
            'submitted-url': 'https://www.google.com/'
        },
        'comment': 'testing',
        'visibility': {
            'code': 'anyone'
        }
    }
}, callback)
```

## Problem:

I get this error when I execute this code: *Can not parse JSON share document.*

Comment: how you're getting the accessToken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your Json data in JSON.stringify(data) then send ,like:

```
 var jsonBody = {
    "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com!",
    "content": {
        "title": "LinkedIn Developers Resources",
        "description": "Leverage LinkedIn's APIs to maximize engagement",
        "submitted-url": "https://developer.linkedin.com",
        "submitted-image-url": "https://example.com/logo.png"
    },
    "visibility": {
        "code": "anyone"
    }
}


body:JSON.stringify(jsonBody)
```

}, callback)